# Using CSS to change the color of sub-menu text on my site

Tags: html, css

I want to change the text of the 3 sub-menu items (under portfolio in the main navigation) on my site to blue. They are currently white and the same color as the background --> [www.ronanmart.in](http://www.ronanmart.in)

Here is the HTML of the navigation

```
<div class="menu-main-navigation-container"><ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-166" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-166"><a href="http://ronanmart.in/blog/">Blog</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-168" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-168"><a href="http://ronanmart.in/portfolio/">Portfolio</a>
<a class="expand" href="#"></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-342" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-342"><a href="http://ronanmart.in/digital-marketing/">Digital Marketing</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-339" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-339"><a href="http://ronanmart.in/creative-media/">Creative Media</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-476" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-476"><a href="http://ronanmart.in/ubikwitty/">Ubikwitty</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-172" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-172"><a href="http://ronanmart.in/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-171" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-171"><a href="http://ronanmart.in/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

I added the following CSS, thinking that specificity would do the trick but it didn't update.

```
#menu-item-342 {
    color: #4486bf;
}

#menu-item-339 {
    color: #4486bf;
}

#menu-item-476 {
    color: #4486bf;
}
```

Feels like I'm missing something obvious but can't figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay great. You are almost there. You just need to target `<a>`. The reason is you need to give the colour for the links and they don't automatically `inherit` like the other elements do. Change your code to either of the below:

```css
#menu-item-342 a {
  color: #4486bf;
}

#menu-item-339 a {
  color: #4486bf;
}

#menu-item-476 a {
  color: #4486bf;
}
```

Also, note that since you have same definition, you can combine them all:

```css
#menu-item-342 a,
#menu-item-339 a,
#menu-item-476 a {
  color: #4486bf;
}
```

**Preview**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the following:

```
ul.submenu li a {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
#menu-item-342 a, #menu-item-339 a, #menu-item-476 a {
   color: #4486bf;
}
```